# Difference between 2 Date fields

Tags: formula, datetime, formatting

In my record I have to datetime fields, now() and Create date. I want to do the difference between them and put this difference in the form:
example:
TOT days TOT hours TOT minutes TOT seconds.
Is it possible in Salesforce?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you done any research? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in formula field:

```
IF(FLOOR( (NOW()- CreatedDate)) > 0,TEXT( FLOOR( (NOW()- CreatedDate)) ) & " days ", "") 
& IF(FLOOR( MOD( (NOW()- CreatedDate)* 24, 24 ) )>0,TEXT( FLOOR( MOD( (NOW()- CreatedDate)* 24, 24 ) ) ) & " hours ","") 
& TEXT( ROUND( MOD( (NOW()- CreatedDate)* 24 * 60, 60 ), 0 ) ) & " minutes "
& TEXT( ROUND( MOD( (NOW()- CreatedDate)* 24 * 60*60, 60 ), 0 ) ) & " seconds"
```

It will display the value like this:

> 19 days 13 hours 7 minutes 53 seconds